Conditional probability of solving next question
Ramu tried 16 questions of a question paper and solved 11 questions. Then, the probability that he will solve the next question will be
a)5/16 b)11/16 c)13/16 d)1
I think whether he can solve the next question is independent over the previous questions ; either he can solve the question or not thus two possibilities hence probability of solving should be 1/2.

Let $~E_1~$ denote the event that Ramu solved exactly $~11~$ of the first $~16~$ questions correctly.  Let $~E_2~$ denote the event that Ramu solves the next question correctly.  You are not given that events $~E_1~$ and $~E_2~$ are independent events.  Further, it is reasonable to surmise that the problem composer intended that the events are not independent, because otherwise, the information given about event $~E_1~$ becomes irrelevant.  What would be the educational value of such a problem?

Why would whether or not he can solve the questions be independent?

More, why would the probability for solving a question be $1/2$ ?  The actual probability is not given, and the evidence is that he has been doing better than a coin flip.

The only correct answer, for the problem as stated, is
e) Not possible to determine from the information given.

Now it could be that the author intended something like the following.
Assume that the events $A_i$ that Ramu solves question $i$ are independent, and each has some probability $p$.  Thus the probability he solves question $17$  is $p$.  But we don't know $p$.
If $X$ is the number of events $A_1$ to $A_{16}$ that occur, then $X/16$ is an unbiased estimator for $p$. In this sense, our best guess of $p$ in this case is $11/16$.
However, without specifying that this is what is assumed and what is desired, the question is worthless.  In particular, it is very bad to claim that $11/16$ is the probability rather than an estimate of the probability.
[EDIT] There is another possible answer, using Laplace's Rule of Succession, a Bayesian interpretation with uniform prior on $[0,1]$, according to which the probability should be $(11+1)/(16+2) = 2/3$.

+1 : My only criticism is that you have to consider your target audience.  I strongly suspect that the subtleties of your answer will escape the original poster, given that the original poster concluded that the probability must be $~(1/2).~$  So, if I was in your position, I would consider starting your response with a reasonable speculation as to the intent of the problem composer, which would explain the (not coincidental) presence of $~11/16~$ as one of the choices.  Then, I would, in a subsequent section of your answer, criticize the problem composer's presumed intent.

For what it's worth, I would draw an analogy of an unfair coin that is flipped $~10~$ times, and comes up heads $~7~$ times.  So, while in an introductory probability course, perhaps given in high school, it is reasonable to presume that the probability of the coin coming up heads is $~(7/10).~$ Then, you can have a field day, criticizing that presumption.

It's worth adding that under the Rule of Succession, 2/3 is also just an estimator, as the expected probability.

@ErikLow Actually, no.  In the context of Bayesian subjective probabilities, $2/3$ is your subjective probability that he solves the next question, given that he has solved $11$ of the last $16$.  In the same vein, Laplace used the Rule of Succession to calculate the probability that the Sun will rise tomorrow, given that it has risen every day for the past 5000 years.
